# Making an Entity's Field Immutable

Tags: hibernate, immutability

In my `Person` entity, let's say I'd like to make an immutable field - `name`.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Long id; 

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  public Person() {} // no-args constructor for Hibernate

  // getter for id and name fields
}
```

As I understand, the following is good enough for Hibernate to retrieve a person based on an `id` look-up - it'll use Hibernate's `setters` for the `id` and `name`.

But, if I want to create a new `Person` with an immutable `name` field, how would I need to change the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor that takes a name arg.  The no-arg constructor needs to exist for Hibernate, but it doesn't need to be public.  Force calling code to use the constructor with name arg.

Or use a static Builder class which would be able to directly set private field; but that seems like overkill in this case.